# How to animate player according to accelerometer in SpriteKit

Tags: animation, ios7, sprite-kit

I am building a jumper game based like MegaJump. I try to animate the player left and right rotation animation (not zRotation) using the following code:

```
// HANDLE ACCELEROMETER L&R

if(_xAcceleration < -kAccelerationDeadZone && (_currentPlayerHeading == PlayerHeadingUp || _currentPlayerHeading == PlayerHeadingUpRight )){

    _currentPlayerHeading = PlayerHeadingUpLeft;
    [_player runAction:_playerAnimationHeadUpLeft];

}
else if (_xAcceleration > kAccelerationDeadZone && (_currentPlayerHeading == PlayerHeadingUp || _currentPlayerHeading == PlayerHeadingUpLeft )) {

    _currentPlayerHeading = PlayerHeadingUpRight;

    [_player runAction:_playerAnimationHeadUpRight];

}
```

Where each of the left and right animations is built from 3-4 frames. The problem is that it won't respond smoothly to the accelerometer changes and I have noticed that in games such as MegaJump the animation is extremely smooth as if it responses to each accelerometer change frame by frame (although the animations there is also created from 3-4 frames per side rotation)

Is there any way to make it work smoother, maybe respond to minor accelerometer changes to display different frames of the animation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't respond smoothly to the accelerometer changes". Does it take longer than expected to run the animation or is it the animation the one that isn't smooth?

Comment: Whereas running an animation of textures you can define the duration each frame is being displayed, when you bind it to accelerometer it rans to fast, or if I use tolerance it looks like broken animation

Answer (score 0):

Following your last answer I suspect your your problem may be that the animation for the same side is running several times and hence causing it to look messed up.

Keep in mind that accelerometer updates are very sensitive, for instance you may get:

```
0.6378
0.8041
0.6424
```

In a fraction of a second and, depending on what your `kAccelerationDeadZone` is it may cause 3 animations to run almost at the same time.

You can try two things:

1.- Create another player state for when it's running an animation and ignore any other update to the player in your accelerometer handler. This way the animation will have to finish before starting another. Depending on how fast you are running those 3-4 frames it may look good or not, for example when changing too fast from Left to Right and back you may find your player running the `_playerAnimationHeadUpRight` animation but moving left...

2.- Don't run animations based on the accelerometer values. Instead just apply player's movement based on these (using the `kAccelerationDeadZone`) and, on your update: method check your player's movement to know if it's moving left or right and, additionally do this check less often than the default 60 times/sec, it's enough to check for direction change a few times every second.

ie:

```
playerTimer += deltaTime;
if (playerTimer >= kPlayerUpdateDelay) {
    if (player.position.x > previousPosition.x) {
        // Moving right
    }else if(player.position.x < previousPosition.x){
        // Moving left
    }
    previousPosition.x = player.position;
}
```

Could also help if you posted the code where you create the animations, just in case.

Let me know any updates.